# Duplicate error

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

So i'm just starting using blender and watching some tutorial when i'm found out my duplicate and my main torus looks like this, can anybody help me out? thanks
[image]

Comment: The rough black spots on the icing are because of two faces in the same mathematical position, fighting over who’s in front. I can’t say why this happened, but that’s what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine and is to be expected.  In most versions of the donut tutorial, you select the top half of the donut, duplicate it, and split it into a separate object to serve as the icing (or else duplicate the whole donut and cut the bottom off one of the copies).  That looks exactly like what you've done.

The weird shading in parts is due to a phenomenon commonly known as [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).  If two faces occupy the same plane in 3D space, there will be some "disagreement" as to who's in front, and you'll get this weird pattern.  In this case, you've duplicated a bunch of donut faces for the icing, and they're still in the same place as the original copies, so that's why you're seeing this.

If you continue the tutorial, you'll see that the next step will fix this problem, either by taking the icing object and resizing or moving it get it away from the donut faces; or else you'll add a solidify modifier to the icing to "thicken" it from a plane into a solid layer, introducing a new set of faces outside the donut.

If you already added the solidify modifier and still see this effect, it's probably because the icing has been solidified *into* the donut.  Go into the solidify settings, and change the "offset" from -1 to +1 (or +1 to -1), so that the icing is solidified *out* of the donut.

Best of luck!

Comment: ah i see now, thanks for your help! have a good day!

Comment: @AnantaWibisana Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).